# npm cannot be found by terminal

Tags: npm, npm-install, package.json

I encounter some errors while using and installing `npm`. This is the command and the error:

```
E:\T&C\Projects\Training Files\bootstrap>npm install -g npm
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1075
  const err = new Error(message);
              ^

Error: Cannot find module '../package.json'
Require stack:
- C:\Users\AmirMahdi\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\lib\cli.js
- C:\Users\AmirMahdi\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js
    at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1075:15)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:920:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1141:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:110:18)
    at createEnginesValidation (C:\Users\AmirMahdi\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\lib\cli.js:7:15)
    at module.exports (C:\Users\AmirMahdi\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\lib\cli.js:78:27)        
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\AmirMahdi\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js:2:25) 
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1254:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1308:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1117:32) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
    'C:\\Users\\AmirMahdi\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\lib\\cli.js',
    'C:\\Users\\AmirMahdi\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js'
  ]
}

Node.js v18.15.0
```

even by uninstalling and installing it again, I have the same error in my terminal. I really didn't find anything helpful; I'll be so glad if you help me solve this annoying problem.